# Have a RadGrid need to add tooltip to column rows

Tags: telerik, tooltip, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid. There is a column called Comments where I currently have it as Y/N
I like to add a tool tip if they hover over the Comments header rows. Is there a easy way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have a RadGrid need to add tooltip to column rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123095/have-a-radgrid-need-to-add-tooltip-to-column-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid2_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Item is GridHeaderItem) 
        { 
            GridHeaderItem header = (GridHeaderItem)e.Item; 
            header["ColumnUniqueName"].ToolTip = "Custom Text"; 
        } 
    }
```