# Have a RadGrid need to add tooltip to column rows

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am using a RadGrid. There is a column called Comments where I currently have it as Y/N
I like to add a tool tip if they hover over the Comments header rows. Is there a easy way of doing this? For a column called CommentsY/N I have values of Y/N. I also have a column called Comments which I am hiding. When the user hovers over CommentsY/N, I like to show the Comments field value.

What I have so far is the following:

What I am trying to do is to hover over the Notes column row and then display the Comments which is also a bound column on the grid. As the comments can be quite lengthy I want to show it when the user hovers over the Notes. Once the hover works, I will make the Comments field not visible. 
Here is what I have but the thing is that when I hover over the Notes, I only see it say Cmmts and it doesn't display the content of the Comments for a given row.

```
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem gridItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.GridColumn column in WtrClients.MasterTableView.RenderColumns)
        {
            if (column is GridBoundColumn)
            {
                //this line will show a tooltip based on the CustomerID data field
                if (column.UniqueName == "Notes")
                {
                    gridItem[column.UniqueName].ToolTip = "Cmmts:" + 
                        Convert.ToString(gridItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[gridItem.ItemIndex]["Comments"]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do an `Label ItemTemplate` in the grid, evaluate whether there is anything in your comments to display a `Y` or `N` and then set the tooltip. :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblOnGrid" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToString(Eval("comments_column")).Equals("") ? "N" : "Y" %>'                                
ToolTip='<%#Eval("comments_column")%>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: IMO, this is the best way to do it!

Comment: Adding to this, it's important to place the `<ItemTemplate>` tag inside a `GridTemplateColumn`

Answer (score -1):

Telerik has a demo on their website which should have everything you need to accomplish this :)

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/targetcontrolsandajax/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid#qsf-demo-source

There was no tags for platform so I assumed (more guess based on your username) ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I have added what I have tried. Basically I am trying to hover over the Notes row and then display the Comments for a given row. I do not get any comments shown though.